# XPath: extract all tags in html page

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm new on XPath and I have a problem. I'd like to extract all and only html tag on a web page.

example:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

my output should be:

```
["<html>", "<body>","<h1>","</h1>","<p>","</p>","</body>"."</html>"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? what isnt working with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex, with the `re.findall` function:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>'''
>>> re.findall('<.*?>', s)
['<html>', '<body>', '<h1>', '</h1>', '<p>', '</p>', '</body>', '</html>']
>>>
```